# Android studio automatically deselects all text when using replacement option "In Selection"

Tags: android, android-studio, replace

If I have selected text and if I put existing text to "Find" textBox and then replace the text in "Find" textBox with text which isn't in selected text, Android studio automatically deselects selected text and I have to select all the text again. How to disable that deselection if it's possible?

Comment: what are you trying to do? I think that's the default behaviour for a search box, if you add a new string to search for, it will deselect the last result and try to find the new one.

Comment: @NikosHidalgo Thanks for comment. Now I see that it's simpler. If I select the text and put non-existent text/letter to a search box, text gets deselcted even if I have checked the box "In Selection", the same behaviour occurs when I clear the text from the text box. It's very annoying that text gets deselcted.